# extreme event time series R

Tags: r, time-series, extreme-value

I'm new into time series and was wondering if there is some implementation in R for decomposing a time series into 'trend', 'extreme value', 'cyclical' and' error'.

I'm dealing with yearly weather data so no seasonal component would make sense but acf suggest some cyclical component and extreme values would also be nice to take into account according to proposed models in literature.
Because of these characteristics I speculate normal arima like fitting would not do the job.

Answer (score 0):

In R, the fpp3 package does nearly everything you are looking for. You can learn more about it from the author's book available for free (from the authors) at https://otexts.com/fpp3/.

Here is some code that will give the decomposition:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fpp3)
decomp <- aus_accommodation %>% 
  model(stl = STL(Occupancy))
components(decomp)
```

Let's see what that returns:

[image: Decomposition]

Once you have that, it's very easy to search for extreme values.

```
df %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  arrange(desc(trend))
```

Let's see what that returns:

[image: trend]

It's very easy to plot the value (Occupancy in this case) and the trend, or any other decomposed feature, such as season_year or season_adjust. This example also breaks it down by state:

```
components(decomp) %>% 
  as_tsibble() %>% 
  autoplot(Occupancy, colour = "gray") +
  geom_line(aes(y = trend, colour = "#D55E00")) +
  labs(y = "Occupancy Rate",
       title = "Plot of occupancy rate") +
  facet_grid(~State) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Let's look at the result:

[image: Occupancy rate and trend]